# Delayed warning messages using suppressWarnings in R script when resetting par()

Tags: r, plot

**Problem:** I'm trying to write a script for an R package and in order to be conscientious to my users I'm saving their graphical parameters before plotting anything so that I can reset them at the end of the script. I understand that it's normal to receive warning messages when doing this because some of them can't be reset, but I'm using `suppressWarnings()` to try to avoid that output reaching the user. Here's a reduced example:

```
Plot4Things <- function(){

    # suppress warnings when saving parameters
    suppressWarnings(opar <- par())

    # adjust parameter
    par(mfrow = c(2,2))

    plot(seq(1,20), pch = 16)
    plot(seq(1,20), pch = 17)
    plot(seq(1,20), pch = 18)
    plot(seq(1,20), pch = 19)

    # suppress warnings while restoring original parameters
    suppressWarnings(par(opar))
}
```

Calling this function the *first time* gives me no warning messages or console output. Just a nice graph, and I verify that the `mfrow` option is reset properly using `par()`. However, each subsequent time I call the `Plot4Things()` function I get the following output:

```
Plot4Things()
Plot4Things()
# There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

The warnings are innocuous things about graphical parameters that can't be reset (which is fine because I'm not trying to). I'm not at all tied to this method of saving/resetting parameters, so is there a better way to do this? Is there a way to get the warning messages to stop making a delayed appearance? Deep down I really just want to understand the behavior so that I can improve my writing in the future.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a general rule, put the resetting into `on.exit`. This guarantees that it is run even if there’s an error in your function that leads to early abort. This should be done for *all* cleanup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set your parameters and save the old ones for restoring, use `no.readonly`:

```
opar <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
```

Then you can avoid using `suppressWarnings` altogether.

And, as mentioned in the comment, put the cleanup into an `on.exit` that you declare directly after saving the `par` at the beginning of your function:

```
opar <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
on.exit(par(opar))
```

As a caveat, the documentation’s example warns, with respect to using `no.readonly`, that

> … this is not in general good practice

… but it doesn’t go on to explain *why*. I would therefore simply ignore this caveat.

Comment: Thanks for the help- I've gone through and changed all of my scripts and am no longer having an issue (still confused at the behavior from `suppressWarnings()` though)